# Get user Id from reference token in API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

My setup,

- An IdentityServer using MVC Identity to store the Users, created with `dotnet new mvc -au Individual` and applying the http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html tutorial, running in localhost 5000.
- A client App, but now I'm using postman to do tests.
- A WEB API, created with `dotnet new webapi`, running in localhost 5001.

The IdentityServer resources and clients configuration is the following, notice that I'm using reference tokens:

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() {
    return new List<IdentityResource>{ new IdentityResources.OpenId() };
}

public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() {
    return new List<ApiResource>{
        new ApiResource("api_resource", "API Resource") {
            Description= "API Resource Access",
            ApiSecrets= new List<Secret> { new Secret("apiSecret".Sha256()) },
        }
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() {
    return new List<Client>{
        new Client {
            ClientId= "angular-client",
            ClientSecrets= { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes= GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            AllowOfflineAccess= true,
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken= true,
            AllowedScopes= { "api_resource" }
        }
}
```

The password and user is send with postman and the token received is send to the WEB API also with postman, something like call `localhost:5001/v1/test` with the token pasted in option `bearer token`.

In the API Startup, in ConfigureServices I'm adding the lines below

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority= "http://localhost:5000";
        options.ApiName= "api_resource";
        options.ApiSecret = "apiSecret";
    });
```

And I'm getting the Id of the user inside the controller as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id) {
    var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:5000");
        var doc = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();


        var introspectionClient = new IntrospectionClient(
            doc.IntrospectionEndpoint,
            "api_resource",
            "apiSecret");

        var token= await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var response = await introspectionClient.SendAsync(
            new IntrospectionRequest { Token = token });

        var userId = response.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;
}
```

The question itself is, **am I using the right path to get the Id from the reference token?**, because now It works but I don't want to miss anything, specially thinking that is a security concern.

I'm asking also because I have seen anothers using

`string userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;`

that is more straightforward but doesn't seems to fit with reference tokens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sub or subject is the user id.  You can use  JwtClaimTypes.Subject , ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier and sometimes even http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier I think it depends upon how the token was parsed.  However if sub works what you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside a controller action that is protected with an `[Authorize]` attribute you can simply get claims directly from the `ClaimsPrinciple`, without having to go through a manual discovery client. The claims principle is handily aliased simply with `User` inside your controllers.

> I'm asking also because I have seen anothers using
>
> string userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type ==
>   ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
>
> that is more straightforward but doesn't seems to fit with reference
>   tokens.

It works just fine with reference tokens. You should have no problems accessing the `sub` claim.

EDIT:
As I mentioned in a comment below, I tend to use the standard [JwtClaimTypes](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/master/source/IdentityModel.Shared/JwtClaimTypes.cs) and create some extension methods on the `ClaimsPrinciple`, such as:

```
public static string GetSub(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    return principal?.FindFirst(x => x.Type.Equals(JwtClaimTypes.Subject))?.Value;
}
```

or

```
public static string GetEmail(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    return principal?.FindFirst(x => x.Type.Equals(JwtClaimTypes.Email))?.Value; 
}
```

... so that within my protected actions I can simply use `User.GetEmail()` to get hold of claim values.
It's worth stating the obvious, that any method for retrieving claim values will only work if the claims actually exist. i.e. asking for the ZoneInfo claim will not work unless that claim was requested as part of the token request in the first place.

Comment: Using `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` gives me `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element`, rather used `"sub"`

Comment: Obviously you can only get out claims that were requested in the first place. I tend to use the [JwtTokenTypes](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/master/source/IdentityModel.Shared/JwtClaimTypes.cs) included in the Identity Model, and then use extension methods such as `public static string GetUserName(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            return principal?.FindFirst(x => x.Type.Equals(JwtClaimTypes.Subject))?.Value;
        }`. So I can just call `User.GetUserName()` in a controller. Change the name and claim type for your purposes.

Comment: @Mashton pls add this as a standalone answer! :)